# Почему это работает?

Tags: bootstrap, sass

```
<li class="nav-item pr-4">
    <a href="#body" class="nav-link active">HOME</a>
</li>    


#navbarCollapse {
      li {
        font-size: 0.9rem;
        a {
          position: relative;
          &:before {
            content: "_";
            position: absolute;
            top: -2px;
            left: -11px;
            font-size: 1rem;
            color: $info;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
          }
          &:hover {
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
          }
          &:hover:before {
            opacity: 1;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    .active {

      &:before {
        opacity: 1 !important;
      }

Делал scrollspy, хотел добавить классу active дефис перед словом. перед этим я добавлял псевдокласс к актив с контеном как у селектора "а", но ничего не работало. потом дошел до того, что просто добавил opacity 1, так как выше он стоит 0, но как связан псевдокласс "а" и "active"? я занимаюсь этим пару месяцев всего, много не знаю еще.
```

Comment: [Кусок верстки бы еще, для понимания...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

**В данном случае не sass, а scss.** Почитайте об различиях данных препроцессоров.
**Ваш код не валиден**, вы вырвали из контекста кусок и хотите получить ответ. Это в корне неправильно.

Ваш код по логике отрабатывает правильно как и должен работать.

В данном случае класс **.active** будет работать на всех элементов где есть данный класс, а не только на теге **a**. Поэтому его необходимо перенести под тег **a** правильно.

Ссылка на готовый результат: https://codepen.io/molof/pen/BaBRLaz

HTML

```
<div id="navbarCollapse">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#!">Псевдоэлемент before не виден</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#!" class="active">Псевдоэлемент before виден</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
#navbarCollapse {
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  li {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    a {
      position: relative;
      &:before {
        content: "_";
        position: absolute;
        top: -2px;
        left: -11px;
        font-size: 1rem;
        color: red;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
      }
      &.active {
        &:before {
          opacity: 1;
        }
      }
      &:hover {
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
      }
      &:hover:before {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ваш класс **.active** необходимо было переместить под тег **a** и указать **&.active** после чего он заработает как и должен был.

Если вы указываете без **&** , то компилятор поймет это вот так **a > .acitve** , а не **a.active** . Будьте внимательнее.

Comment: Прошу прощения за кривое повествование, я просто не понял, почему псевдокласс before для "а" и "active" работает как один, то есть я думал, что нужно писать отдельно before для "а" и для "active". для "а", чтобы при наведении курсора появлялся дефис, и для "active", чтобы выделялся активный элемент с дефисом. а оказалось, что достаточно поставить opacity 1, чтобы это работало, хотя в в нем больше ничего нет, то есть он взял данные из a:before.